# Tornado error about attributes when deploying a server

Tags: python, server, tornado

I'm trying to run a program that works with Tornado (https://github.com/oduwsdl/CarbonDate), however, when I try to deploy a server with it, I get multiple errors from Tornado. I'm a bit exhausted, so it might be a dumb question, but could anyone help me understand what this error is/how to solve it? I have already installed and updated all the necessary packages to get it working, along with upgrading nbconvert, but I still get the error.

```
$ sudo ./main.py -l https://theuselessweb.com/

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/h311p0w517/programs/CarbonDate/./main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import server
  File "/home/h311p0w517/programs/CarbonDate/server.py", line 22, in <module>
    class CarbonDateServer(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  File "/home/h311p0w517/programs/CarbonDate/server.py", line 27, in CarbonDateServer
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
AttributeError: module 'tornado.web' has no attribute 'asynchronous'
```

Answer (score 1):

`@tornado.web.asynchronous` decorator was removed in Tornado v6. The github repo you linked is very old.

To run this code, you should install an older version of Tornado. Try version `5.1` or `4.5`.